# python find intersection timeranges in array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

i have a python numpy array with two rows. One row describes the start time of an event and the other one describes the end (here times as epoch integers). The code example means, that the event at index=0 starts at time=1 and ends at time=7.

```
start = [1, 8, 15, 30]
end   = [7, 16, 20, 40]

timeranges = np.array([start,end])
```

I want to know, if the time ranges are intersected. That means i need a function/algorithm, that calculates the information, that the time range from 8 to 16 is intersected with the time range from 15 to 20.

My solution is, to use two intersected loops and check if any start time or end time is within an other timerange. But with ipython it lasts very long, because my **timeranges** are filled with nearly 10000 events.

Is there an elegant solution, to get the result in "short" time (e.g. below one minute)?

Comment: So, the output would be simply a flag (True/False)?

Comment: I would like to get the index where this happens, because it indicates a failure.

Comment: So, what's the exact output for the listed sample data? Also, is the data already sorted for the start and end?

Comment: the list is not sorted. The output should deliver the information for every intersection in a way i can find the responding index in the array. My loop solution delivers for this case: 'end_index=1, intersect_index=2' and 'start_index=2, intersect_index=1'. It is enough if one of them is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the data as a collection of `(time,index_in_list,start_or_end)`. For example, if the input data is:

```
start = [1, 8, 15, 30]
end   = [7, 16, 20, 40]
```

Transform the input data to a list of tuples as follows:

```
def extract_times(times,is_start):
   return [(times[i],i,is_start) for i in range(len(times))]
```

Which yields:

```
extract_times(start,true) == [(1,0,true),(8,1,true),(15,2,true),(30,3,true)]
extract_times(end,false) == [(7,0,false),(16,1,false),(20,2,false),(40,3,false)]
```

Now, merge the two lists and store them.
Then, start traversing the lists from beginning to end, each time keeping track of the currently intersecting intervals, updating the state based on whether each new tuple is a beginning or and ending of an interval. This way you'll find all overlaps.

The complexity is `O(n log(n))` for the sorting plus some overhead if there are lots of intersections.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the input lists might not be sorted and to handle cases where we might see timeranges with multiple intersections, here's a brute-force comparison based method using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.argwhere(np.triu(timeranges[1][:,None] > timeranges[0],1))
```

**Sample runs**

Original sample case :

```
In [81]: timeranges
Out[81]: 
array([[ 1,  8, 15, 30],
       [ 7, 16, 20, 40]])

In [82]: np.argwhere(np.triu(timeranges[1][:,None] > timeranges[0],1))
Out[82]: array([[1, 2]])
```

Multiple intersections case :

```
In [77]: timeranges
Out[77]: 
array([[ 5,  7, 18, 12, 19],
       [11, 17, 28, 19, 28]])

In [78]: np.argwhere(np.triu(timeranges[1][:,None] > timeranges[0],1))
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

If by **`within`** in `"if any start time or end time is within an other timerange"`, you meant the boundaries are inclusive, change the comparison of **`>`** to **`>=`** in the solution code.